# Finding side of triangle?

Tags: geometry

this is probably a basic question but I haven't taken a geometry class since high school

My professor wants us to create a program that tells the user to enter three points (x1,y1),(x2,y2), and (x3,y3) to ultimately find the area of a triangle

she wants us to use this formula; s=(side1+side2+side3) then area^2 = ( s(s-side1)(s-side2)(s-side3) )

My question is how do I get the sides??

Comment: distance formula?

Comment: 1) [Pythragorean theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem). e.g. side1 = distance between 2 and 3 = $\sqrt{(x_2-x_3)^2 + (y_2-y_3)^2}$, 2) The correct [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron's_formula) for area is Area^2 = s(s-side1)(s-side2)(sside3) where s = (side1+side2+side3)$\color{red}{/2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to approach to the solution. Is use the following:

> Let $A=(x_1,y_1)$, $B=(x_2,y_2)$ and $C=(x_3,y_3)$ points in a plane. The area of the triangle $ABC$ is $$[ABC]=\frac12 \left| \begin{matrix} 1&x_1&y_1\\1&x_2&y_2\\1&x_3&y_3\end{matrix}\right|$$

Then you only have to find a determinant, and if you do not want negative area, apply absolute value to the final answer.

Answer (score -1):

Use the co-ordinates given to you by the  user. Assuming they are in order or appearance, x =x2 - x1 gives you the horizontal length of the side, and y = y2-y1 gives you the vertical distance, from there you take sqrt ( x^2 + y^2) and volia, you have your side length. Repeat for the other sides and then use the formula your professer gave